# Closing contours along boundary lines

Tags: qgis, contour

This is what happens when I use line to polygon

[image]

But I want the contour line to close along the boundary of the picture, like this
[image]
I want to use contour lines to generate contour plane

What should I do?

Comment: thank you I want to use contour lines to generate contour plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `Merge vector layers` to merge your contour lines and boundary line.
2. Use `Polygonize` on the merged layer.

In order for this to work, your boundary line should intersect each of the outer contour lines. Your screenshot seems to show some small gaps between the contours and boundary line, if your real data contains these gaps you'll need to edit your data to remove the gaps first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are some gaps between the boundary line and the contour line. I'll try to adjust it. How to use merging lines? Will the value of contour lines change?

Comment: From the Processing Toolbox, go to 'Vector general' > 'Merge vector layers'. Under 'Input layers' you select both you contour and boundary layers. The attribute value of the contour lines won't change from merging, however the attribute values will be lost when you polygonize, so you may need to determine a method to apply suitable attributes to your polygons. Each polygon is the area between two contour lines, so neither line attribute would be correct to apply to the polygon directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using

> contour polygons

solves my problem。
Search in the toolbar

> contour polygons

,Generate contour files directly from DEM.
I wanted to generate a contour file by generating contour lines and then converting lines to polygons.
But now QGIS can directly generate contour polygons without graphical errors, which is what I want.